# The logic behind rearranging summations - generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions

I'm learning about generating functions, and one part that I am struggling with is the logic behind rearranging summations (particularly double summations).

I'll illustrate an example:

Using the Lagrangean Inversion theorem, I get that the $z^n$ coefficient is given by: 
$$S_n=\frac{1}{n}[u^{n-1}]\left(\frac{1-u}{1-2u}\right)^n$$
Expanding this out I get:

$$S_n=\frac{1}{n}[u^{n-1}]\sum^{n}_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^ku^k * \sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\binom{j+n-1}{j}(2u)^j$$
Which I have brought together as:
$$\frac{1}{n}[u^{n-1}]\sum^{n}_{k=0}\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\binom{n}{k}\binom{j+n-1}{j}2^j(-1)^ku^{j+k}$$
Where I'm using the fact that (taken from my course notes):
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{p+1}}=\sum_q\binom{q+p}{q}$$
I know the answer is:

$$S_n=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_k(-2)^k\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$

*My Problem*

I can't work out the reasoning that allows you to bring the double summation together in the type of situation. I'm fairly sure I need to apply the restriction $j+k=n-1$, since that is the coefficient we are interested in, but I don't know where to go.

(For reference, this is I.41 on pg70 of Analytic Combinatorics by Flajolet and Sedgewick, available as a free download via a simple Google search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that

$$\frac{1}{n}[u^{n-1}]\sum^{n}_{k=0}\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\binom{n}{k}\binom{j+n-1}{j}2^j(-1)^ku^{j+k}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_k(-2)^k\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{n+k-1}{k}\;.$$

The only terms that need to be considered on the lefthand side are those for which $j+k=n-1$, so we can let $j$ run from $0$ to $n-1$ and take $k=n-1-j$ to reduce the lefthand side to

$$\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1-j}\binom{j+n-1}j2^j(-1)^{n-1-j}\;.$$

Now rename $j$ to $k$:

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1-k}\binom{k+n-1}k2^k(-1)^{n-1-k}\;.$$

Finally,

$$\binom{n}{n-1-k}=\binom{n}{n-(n-1-k)}=\binom{n}{k+1}\;,$$

and $2^k(-1)^{n-1-k}=2^k(-1)^{n-1+k}=(-2)^k(-1)^{n-1}$, so

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1-k}\binom{k+n-1}k2^k(-1)^{n-1-k}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-2)^k\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{n+k-1}k\;,$$

as desired.

**Added:** If instead we let $k$ run from $0$ to $n-1$ and take $j=n-1-k$, the lefthand side becomes

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}k\binom{(n-1-k)+n-1}{n-1-k}2^{n-1-k}(-1)^k\;.$$

Letting $\ell=n-1-k$ and noting that

$$\binom{n}k=\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{n}{\ell+1}\;,$$

we can rewrite this as

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1n\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{\ell+1}\binom{\ell+n-1}{\ell}2^\ell(-1)^{n-1-\ell}&=\frac1n\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{\ell+1}\binom{\ell+n-1}{\ell}2^\ell(-1)^{n-1+\ell}\\\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}(-2)^\ell\binom{n}{\ell+1}\binom{n+\ell-1}\ell\;,
\end{align*}$$

exactly as before except that the index variable is $\ell$ instead of $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to make sure I've got this clear in my head, you're saying that $n-1$ is constant and known, we choose $j$ to be the parameter that we "control" and leave $k$ to be whatever it needs to be to satisfy the restriction? Could we just as easily make $k$ the parameter we control and let $j$ be whatever it needs to be, then remove the summation on $j$? I've tried doing that and I get something quite different:$$\frac{2^{n-1}}{n}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}\binom{2n-2-k}{n-1}(-1/2)^k$$ Does this make any sense at all?

Comment: @Phill: I actually originally did it making $k$ the parameter and then switched when I realized that doing so would save a step or two. I’ve added the alternative approach. What you have is correct – it’s the most straightforward simplification of the first displayed line in the addition – but with a bit of work it can be simplified in to the desired result, as I did above.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Phill: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different derivation.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{n}&[u^{n-1}]\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k}\binom{j+n-1}{j}2^j(-1)^ku^{j+k}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[u^{n-1-k}]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k}\binom{j+n-1}{j}2^j(-1)^ku^{j}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[u^{k}]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{j+n-1}{j}2^j(-1)^{n-k-1}u^{j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{k+n-1}{k}(-2)^k\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the rule $[u^p]u^qA(u)=[u^{p-q}]A(u)$ with $p=n-1$ and $q=k$. We also set the upper limit of the outer sum to $n-1$ since the exponent of $u^{n-1-k}$ is non-negative.
- In (2) we change the order of summation $k\rightarrow n-1-k$ and apply the rule $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $u^k$ and factor out $(-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Nice answer. (+1). Brian Scott has not been on the site for quite some time now.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks, Marko! :-)